# My Body Won't Slide Over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote up this JQuery/JavaScript to slide a menu into the website, and the body moves out of the way, but the body doesn't seem to be moving out of the way. The menu does slide in, only the body doesn't. I've posted all my JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.

```js
var main = function(){
$('.icon').click(function()
{
$('.menu').animate({
left: "0px"
}, 200);

$('body').animate({
left:"300px"
}, 200);
});
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 background-image: url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/U7rb02o.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 left: 0px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
}
.menu {

 background-image: url((https
://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-cubes-pattern_1053-248.jpg))
 background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/white-cubes-pattern_1053-248.jpg");
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-position: left top;
 background-image: url(http://wallpapers.ae/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Black-Pattern-Background-Wallpaper.jpg);
 height: 100%;
 width: 300px;
 position: fixed;
 left: -300px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.icon {
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-left: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
 width: 75px;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JQuery Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="body">
<div class="icon">

</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add it as an snippet?

Comment: And add your CSS file

Comment: And an <i> element which the js has a click handler on

Comment: I just added my CSS file. Sorry for responding so late.